# VB to Microsoft Access Database - WHERE Spend Date >='" & StartMonth & "'"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

I am using Microsoft Access as my data source in Visual Studio and want to input a query into it to return a value.

Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Spend]", MyConn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Spend")
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view

    MyConn.Open()
    StartMonth = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("01/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    query = "Select Amount from [Spend] WHERE Spend Date >='" & StartMonth & "'"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, MyConn)
    TotalCost = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    MyConn.Close()
 End Sub
End Class
```

I am receiving this error:

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Spend Date >='01/01/2016 13:46:50''

Can anyone help?

Comment: @BinaryWorrier I have done that now but it still shows up the records from before the date I have specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Access, you should use:

```
StartMonth = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'01 HH:mm:ss")
query = "Select Amount from [Spend] WHERE [Spend Date] >= #" & StartMonth & "#"
```

Comment: What are the 's for?  `"yyyy/MM/01 HH:mm:ss"` produces the same resut.

Comment: No, that depends - there is a world outside the US. `/` on its own is not a _slash_ but the _date separator_. If quotes are omitted, it will be replaced in the string with whatever is your local date separator - in some countries this will be a Space. To force a literal slash, wrap it in quotes.

Comment: OK - good to known. I think this works as well `"yyyyMM01 HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: No, that will fail in Access. MySQL may read it, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my problem.

If you have a column name separated by a space, such as 'Spend Date'

You MUST enclose it in brackets like this [Spend Date]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the date in `#` not `'`

[Examples of using dates as criteria in Access queries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-Access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762)